# Mysql query to replace empty string with default value on update

Tags: mysql

How to replace empty string with default value on update?
I am getting this error

> Error Number: 1366
>       Incorrect decimal value: '' for column 'actualcost' at row 1

I have set default value as 0.00 and decimal datatype for 'actualcost' field.

Update query:

```
 UPDATE `campaign` SET  `productid` = '29', `actualcost` = '',`expectedrevenue` = '0.00', `actualresposecount` = '0', `actualsalescount` = '0', `actualroi` = '0.00' WHERE `campaignid` = '90'
```

Comment: better to include your table structure in your question.

Comment: Default values are invoked when the query omits the column from the inserted column list. AFAIK the only reasonable way to accomplish this would be to programmatically omit the column (ie change the query) when the value provided is blank

Comment: Also include your update statement. Everything that's useful to know in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Although some databases, like Postgres, allow the eyword `DEFAULT` to be used as the inserted value to have the effect you're after

Answer (score 0):

Mysql (and postgres, probably others) allows the use of the keyword `DEFAULT` instead of a value to have the default value inserted, eg:

```
insert into mytable (id, text_column_with_default)
values (1, default)
```

If you change blank value to this keyword, you'll achieve your goal.

It'll mean you won't be able to use a prepared statement with placeholders; you'll have to build the SQL string yourself.